# html/php form at least 1 field required

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I’m making a form which is used to order some products.

However I have 11 fields where the customer can enter how many of that product they would like.

```
 <tr>
    <td>Pizza Fungi</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="PizzaFungi" size="3" maxlength="3"></td>
 </tr>
```

When they press submit it redirects to another page where all their info is shown – name, address, phone number, and finally the products they filled in.

But that is my problem, when they fill in nothing it just redirects to the other page where nothing will show (obviously).

What I need is some kind of validator in which I can select a group of fields. (only the items and not name, phone number etc.) And it will return an error of some kind.

Thanks a lot in advance and if you miss any information, I’ll edit.

EDIT: It’s not only 1 pizza – that is just 1 of the 11 products. How do I make it so that only 1 of those 11 is required?

Answer (score 1):

Use required attribute of HTML5.

```
<input type="text" name="PizzaFungi" size="3" maxlength="3" required></td>
```

As per your requirement I have used jQuery to check atleast one field is filled.

```
 <script>
  var count=0;
  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("form").submit(function(){

           $("input[type=text]").each(function(){

               if($(this).val()=="")count++
       });
      var isAllowToSubmit=(count<11);
      if(!isAllowToSubmit) alert("Please fill all the fields")
      count=0;  
      return isAllowToSubmit;
        }); 
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: isnt it possible to manipulate that so its basically not a validation?

Comment: I just suggested to use advance power of HTML5 which has predefined attributes for the same.Thanks.

Comment: Yes.It makes particular input field required with predefined dialog box showing the HTML5 error that Fill that field

Comment: I don't know if my question wasn't clear enough.
But there are 11 products in my form, and at least 1 of them needs to have it's input field filled in before the form submits.

This one pizza fungi was an example in my form, there are actually 11 different input fields. So making this specific one required isn't really helping me

Answer (score 1):

If-Conditions are your friend.

```
if(!empty($_POST['PizzaFungi'])) {
    //1 field is filled
}
```